Nature of a complementary tile in a doubly periodic bi-tiling from a probability distribution
I was playing around with some simulations using this code with beta distributions:
(* Parameters for the simulation *)
numSamples = 1000000; (* Total number of samples to generate *)
a1 = 1; a2 = 100; (* Range for alpha *)
b1 = 1; b2 = 100; (* Range for beta *)

(* Function to generate one sample from a Beta distribution with random alpha and beta,
   scaled to the new support [0, 3*Sqrt[3]] *)
generateSample[] := Module[{alpha, beta, y},
  alpha = RandomReal[{a1, a2}];
  beta = RandomReal[{b1, b2}];
  y = RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[alpha, beta]];  (* y is in [0, 1] *)
  3*Sqrt[3]*y  (* Scale y to [0, 3*Sqrt[3]] *)
];

(* Generate multiple samples *)
samples = Table[generateSample[], {numSamples}];


SmoothHistogram[samples,Automatic,"PDF",Axes->False] 

Which gave this image:

But then I flipped it and combined it with the original to create this:

And it seems that it does tile:

If I put a horizontal line through the new tile to break it in half, would this also be a probability distribution? Are there any interesting probability properties in relation between the two tiles other than that I can make a tiling from them? I don't know if there is a closed formula known for either shape.
Just some curious thoughts.
